# ASP.NET MVC 2.0: Shared View Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a pretty basic question, but I cannot find the answer online without resorting to asking it myself. In an ASP.NET MVC 2 WebSite, if I have a Shared view located in a Shared folder. Let's say the view is called Error, where is the controller for this View? Do I create a SharedController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create a `SharedController`.  In any controller you want the view available, either create a Method called `Error` or have a Method return `View("Error")`.

Basically if MVC can't find the View in the Controller Named Directory it looks in the Shared folder for it (which also works for Partial Views and Controls).

Comment: Hmmm.. What if I want the view to be available in ALL controllers? Can I just create the Method in a base controller and have them all inherit?

Comment: That certainly is one way to go about it.  I never had a need for that.